# How to calculate volume of convex hull and volume of a 3D object

Tags: graphics3d, computational-geometry

I have a set of random 3D data points.

How can I calculate the volume of the convex hull?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The "area" of fig01 is not well defined. The usual definiton of "Area" applies to 2D surfaces, not to point sets

Comment: For your new question, see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedron#Volume).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This following code that uses `TetGen` we will compute the volume of the convex hull.

```
Needs["TetGenLink`"];
TetraMaker[pts_, surface_, TetGenString_?StringQ] := 
Module[{inInst, outInst, coords, surface1, meshElements, facets},
      inInst = TetGenCreate[];
      TetGenSetPoints[inInst, pts];
      facets = Partition[surface, 1];
      TetGenSetFacets[inInst, facets];
      outInst = TetGenTetrahedralize[inInst, TetGenString];
      coords = TetGenGetPoints[outInst];
      surface1 = TetGenGetFaces[outInst];
      meshElements = TetGenGetElements[outInst];
      {coords, surface1, meshElements}
     ];
TetrahedraVolume = Compile[{{coords, _Real, 2}, {elements, _Integer, 1}},
Block[{p},
      p = coords[[elements]];
      1/6*Abs[Det[p[[ {1, 2, 3}]] - p[[{2, 3, 4}]]]]
], RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
];
```

Some 3D data

```
data3D = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {65, 3}];
```

Compute the convex hull and then call the above function to form the tetrahedralization. Then call `TetrahedraVolume` to compute the **volume**.

```
{pts, surface} = TetGenConvexHull[data3D];
{coords, surface1, meshElements} = TetraMaker[pts, surface, "pqa2.8"];
Total[ TetrahedraVolume[coords, meshElements]]
```

> 505.135

You can use this to compute **surface area** of a triangulated 3D geometry

```
TriangleArea[pts_List?(Length[#] == 3 &)] := 
Norm[Cross[pts[[2]] - pts[[1]], pts[[3]] - pts[[1]]]]/2
TriangleArea[{pts[[#[[1]]]], pts[[#[[2]]]], pts[[#[[3]]]]}] & /@ surface // Total
```

> 337.121

I compute the area of the triangles separately and adding them gives me the area of the **surface** that defines the convex hull.
[image]

In the above picture first you see the convex hull in black lines. The middle one shows the blue surface mesh created by `TetGen` during tetrahedralization. In the last one you can see the cell volumes of the tetrahedrons that discretize the volume of the convex hull in different random colors. We get the total volume by adding the volumes of these tetrahedrons.

### Volume for **Convex Hull** of the point cloud in your data

```
data3D = Import["http://dl.dropbox.com/u/68983831/object.vtk", "VertexData"];
{pts, surface} = TetGenConvexHull[data3D];
{coords, surface1, meshElements} = TetraMaker[pts, surface, "pqa2.8"];
Total[ TetrahedraVolume[coords, meshElements]]
```

> 3120.05

### Volume for **3D Geometry** in your data

```
surface = Import["http://dl.dropbox.com/u/68983831/object.vtk", "PolygonData"];
{coords, surface1, meshElements} = TetraMaker[pts, surface, "pqa.8"];
Total[TetrahedraVolume[coords, meshElements]]
```

> 1622.23

[image]
**Code for Graphics**

```
p1 = Graphics3D[{{Red, PointSize[0.03], Point[data3D]}, {Yellow, 
Opacity[.8], EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], 
GraphicsComplex[pts, Polygon[surface]]}}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> True]; 
p2 = Graphics3D[{{Red, PointSize[0.03], 
Point[data3D]}, {EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], FaceForm[None], 
GraphicsComplex[pts, Polygon[surface]]}, {Yellow, Opacity[.8], 
EdgeForm[Blue], GraphicsComplex[coords, Polygon[surface1]]}},
Boxed -> False, Axes -> True];
p3 = Graphics3D[{{Red, PointSize[0.03], Point[data3D]}, 
Table[With[{p = 
    RGBColor[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 3]]}, {Blend[{Lighter[Yellow, .8],
      Red, Yellow}, i/Length@meshElements], Glow[Darker[p, .5]], 
   Specularity[White, 20], Opacity[.2], EdgeForm[p], 
   GraphicsComplex[coords, 
    Polygon@Partition[meshElements[[i]], 3, 1, 1]]}], {i, 1, 
  Length@meshElements}]}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> True];
GraphicsGrid[Transpose@{{p1, p2, p3}}, Spacings -> {0, 0},ImageSize -> 600]
```

Comment: There's a less messy way to compute surface area: `Total[Flatten[Normal[GraphicsComplex[pts, Polygon[surface]]]] /. Polygon -> TriangleArea]`

Answer (score 6):

Taken together, PlatoManiac's answer and J.M.'s comment show how to do this.  Here's code:

```
Needs["TetGenLink`"];
data3D = Import["http://dl.dropbox.com/u/68983831/object.vtk", "VertexData"]; 
{pts, surface} = TetGenConvexHull[data3D];
volumeContribution[{v1_, v2_, v3_}] := With[
   {n = Cross[v2 - v1, v3 - v1]}, Abs[v1.n]/2];
triangles = pts[[#]] & /@ surface;
Total[volumeContribution /@ triangles]/3
```

20491.

Comment: I think that should be `v1.n` on the fifth line, not `Abs[v1.n]`.

Comment: @ MarkMcClure: Thanks +1

Answer (score 4):

Use [RegionMeasure](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMeasure.html) and [ConvexHullMesh](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConvexHullMesh.html).  Example:

```
points = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 3}]

RegionMeasure@ConvexHullMesh[points]

(* ==> 0.948199 *)
```

Comment: This is clearly a forgotten gem +1.