# ListPointPlot3d to visualize points close to a manifold

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, visualization

I have a large set of points that are close to manifold which I want to show in a `ListPointPlot3D`. Using part of the data set illustrates this

[plot http://vollmer.ms/homog3d_0](http://vollmer.ms/homog3d_0)

[plot http://vollmer.ms/homog3d_1](http://vollmer.ms/homog3d_1)

there are fewer data points in the middle.

But using all the data with

```
ListPointPlot3D[list[[2 ;; n]]]
```

results in

[plot http://vollmer.ms/homog3d_2](http://vollmer.ms/homog3d_2)

Is there a better way to visualize this? Somehow something like 3d contour plot of the density.

Comment: Please note that part of your question is missing.

Comment: I am really sorry

Comment: Have you tried [ContourPlot3D](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ContourPlot3D.html)?

Comment: yes as well as ListContourPlot

Comment: Although the title doesn't mention it, this seems to be about fitting a surface to a point list. If so, it's a possible duplicate of [Construct a simple mesh or tetrahedral mesh from 3D image surface](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7188/245)

Comment: A theme that generally needs this kind of computation is the SPH computational fluid dynamics method, where a "continuous" mass of water is processed as a very big set of "drops" of water. At the end, to render it, you need algorithms to regroup then into a surface. Since this method is also used on game development, you should be able to find a lot of algorithms  (not on Mathematica...) by searching by that theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your point cloud is extremely "thick" you can create a *RegionFunction*. Here is a simple example using points in the cube from -1 to 1 in all directions.

```
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10^5, 3}];

ListPointPlot3D[pts, BoxRatios -> 1]
```

[image]

Now create the function.

```
nf = Nearest[pts];

inRegion[pt : {_Real, _Real, _Real}, eps_Real] := 
 TrueQ[Norm[nf[pt, 1][[1]] - pt] < eps]
```

This will give an approximation to the boundary enclosing the region. We decide a point is "in" if it is within .04 of one of the points in the original list, else it is outside.

```
d = 1.5;
reg = RegionPlot3D[
  inRegion[{x, y, z}, .04], {x, -d, d}, {y, -d, d}, {z, -d, d}, 
  Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> 40]
```

[image]

This code was gleefully cribbed from some work [here](http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/~ley/db/conf/adg/adg2010.html) (Also [here](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-25070-5_6))

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. The problem with this approach is that I have outliers, and they get a ball around them, too. I am trying to use the cluster function, but this does not seem to work.

Comment: Try it with Norm[nf[pt, 2][[2]] - pt]; that should force there to be at least two nearby points in order to be considered "inside".

Comment: that is good but terribly slow..

Comment: I'm mildly surprised about the speed issue. Can you give details on how to produce a data set typical of the sort you encounter?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @Daniel Lichtblau described, let me give you a further idea. It is not completely clear whether it really helps in your case since frome the statement

> I have a large set of points that are close to manifold

I can only guess and an example data-set would have been better.

What I would try is to estimate the local density of points and to make a `ContourPlot3D` (or a `RegionPlot3D`) which shows you the boundary of certain density.

You could for instance (and this is the difference to Daniels approach) calculate the distances from a point `x` to the next, say 30 points and then calculate the `Mean` or `Median` distance. This gives you kind of an estimation how dense `x` is surrounded by points.

Example:

```
data = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "StanfordBunny"}, "VertexData"];
With[{nf = Nearest[data]},
 density[x : {__?NumericQ}] := Mean[Map[Norm[x - #] &, nf[x, 30]]]
 ];
RegionPlot3D[
 density[{x, y, z}] < .01, {x, -.15, .1}, {y, -.1, .1}, {z, 0, .2}, 
 BoxRatios -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 40]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I like that. Could be useful in situations where sample points are relatively sparse. What I did kinda falls flat in such areas. (Plus 1, as they say. Whoever "they" is.)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks but it's stolen or at least inspired by the [Kernel density estimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation).