# Meshing the surface of a non-convex object

Tags: mesh, tetgenlink

I would like to mesh the surface of a cloud of points that may not be completely convex, for example the points in this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50668/how-to-map-vertex-points-from-the-surface-of-a-curved-tube-onto-2d-plane).
Mathematica does not provide triangulation of 3D points, but there is a link to TetGen

```
 Needs["TetGenLink`"]

 {mypts, mysurface} = TetGenConvexHull[dat];
 Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[mypts, Polygon[mysurface]], Boxed -> False]
```

which results in this

[image]

Notice it doesn't get the surface meshing associated with subtle twist in the curved shape, and meshes points further away in the goal of creating a convex object. I suppose one could try to mesh the surface piece by piece and slowly merge it as in this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7194/9831), but that sounds like a nightmare.

Here is the cloud of points for reference:

[image]

Comment: @Öskå I asked myself the same question today lol, then decided to play around with it.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I didn't check the beginning of the question :) Deleting comments!

Comment: One can easily get [that](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7gcI9.png)

Comment: @Öskå Does it contain the surface polygons ? If that is the case that is what I need.

Comment: Generally, `ListSurfacePlot3D` can do this.  However, it won't work well for this particular point cloud.  It will work for the other, straight tube that he posted.  Representing a surface as a list of points is not precise, and it's generally not a good idea.  For example: where are the holes in the surface?  However, in some cases this is the only (experimental) data one has.

Comment: I don't think it does, it is, as Szabolcs pointed, made with `ListSurfacePlot3D`.

Comment: @Szabolcs representing a surface as a list of points should be fine. And generally that is how most 3D models are build, we usually push them through a 3D-delaunay triangulator and pick the surface polygons. The software that I have used in the past usually has options for convex or not-convex (concave). This is usually done on a surface you have a high sampling to avoid exactly what you mentioned, missing some important topological feature. I think TetGen actually has this capability but doesn't seem to be included with the link, but I could be mistaken

Comment: @Szabolcs Actually given belisarius's answer I might try to redo this with matlab delaunay using your MATLink, since I think it might be a bit faster. But I will need to double check.

Comment: @lalmei If you solve it with MATLink/MATLAB, drop me a mail.  I'm curious.

Comment: Can you repost the data on pastebin, the link above seems dead. I'm trying to write a solution with the functions introduced in **V10**.

Comment: @RunnyKine that wasn't my question I linked to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using [Simon's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8812/193) (all credit to him):

```
Needs["TetGenLink`"]
file = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/68983831/curved_pipe02.txt";
dat = Import[file, "Table"];
{pts, tetrahedra} = TetGenDelaunay[dat];
csr[{aa_, bb_, cc_, dd_}] := 
 With[{a = aa - dd, b = bb - dd, c = cc - dd}, 
  Norm[a.a Cross[b, c] + b.b Cross[c, a] + 
     c.c Cross[a, b]]/(2 Norm[a.Cross[b, c]])]
radii = csr[pts[[#]]] & /@ tetrahedra;
alphashape[rmax_] := Pick[tetrahedra, radii, r_ /; r < rmax]
faces[tetras_] := 
 Flatten[tetras /. {a_, b_, c_, 
     d_} :> {{a, b, c}, {a, b, d}, {a, c, d}, {b, c, d}}, 1]
externalfaces[faces_] := 
 Cases[Tally[Sort /@ faces], {face_, 1} :> face]
polys = externalfaces@faces@alphashape[.001];
Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[pts, Polygon@polys], Boxed -> False]

polys = externalfaces@faces@alphashape[.001];
Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[pts, Polygon@polys], Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Ah! Concave the other word for Non-convex that I didn't search for!