# How to calculate the volume of a convex hull?

Tags: numerical-integration, symbolic, computational-geometry

Given a spatial curve represented by a [parametric equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation#3D_examples), is it possible in *Mathematica* 9 to calculate symbolically (or at least numerically) the volume of its [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull)?

Comment: Can you give s a hint about the kind of parametric curve you want to look at, and perhaps some code to work with?

Comment: duplicate : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6908/5467

Comment: That doesn't quite seem to be a duplicate, @andre, because there the data are given in a different form. In principle there should be a formula for computing the volume in terms of a suitable integrals over the curve.

Comment: @whuber sorry. Also : related question

Comment: It does provide a feasible numerical solution though.

Answer (score 14):

Here is a way to do it numerically:

Reap the points from a parametric plot:

```
pf = {Cos[u], Sin[u] + Cos[v], Sin[v]};
data = Reap[
    ParametricPlot3D[
     Sow[pf], {u, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {v, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]][[2, 1]];
```

Get all the numeric values, pack the data and delete the duplicates:

```
pts = Cases[data, {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}];
pts = DeleteDuplicates[Developer`ToPackedArray@N[pts]];
```

To look at the points:

```
Graphics3D[Point[pts], Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Load TetGenLink and compute and visualize the convex hull:

```
<<TetGenLink`
ch = TetGenConvexHull[pts];
Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[ch[[1]], Polygon[ch[[2]]]], Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Compute the delaunay mesh of the convex hull, write a function to compute the volume of a tetrahedron, apply it and total the volume of the tetrahedra:

```
dt = TetGenDelaunay[pts];
tetVol = Compile[{{coords, _Real, 2}, {incidents, _Integer, 1}}, 
   Block[{a, b, c, d},
    {a, b, c, d} = coords[[incidents]];
    1/6*Det[Transpose[{a, c, b}] - d]
    ], RuntimeAttributes -> Listable];

Total[tetVol @@ dt]
(* 12.5 *)
```

Sanity check: for a sphere we get:

```
pf = {Sin[u]*Sin[v], Cos[u]*Sin[v], Cos[v]};
4.138` - 4./3*\[Pi]*1^3
(*-0.05*)
```

which seams reasonable.

**Update:**

As suggested by Daniel Lichtblau, this also works for parametric curves:

```
pf = {(t^2 - 1)/(t^2 + 1), 
   2 t/(t^2 + 1), ((t^2 - 1)/(t^2 + 1))^2 - (2 t/(t^2 + 1))^2};
data = Reap[ParametricPlot3D[Sow[pf], {t, -10, 10}]][[2, 1]];
pts = Cases[data, {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}];
pts = DeleteDuplicates[Developer`ToPackedArray@N[pts]];
Graphics3D[Point[pts], Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

```
<< TetGenLink`
ch = TetGenConvexHull[pts];
Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[ch[[1]], Polygon[ch[[2]]]], Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

And what I find most amazing is the suggestion from george2079:

```
shoelace3rd = Compile[{{coords, _Real, 2}, {tris, _Integer, 2}},
   -Total[Det[coords[[#]]] & /@ tris]/6
   ];
shoelace3rd @@ ch
(* 3.12 *)
```

Comment: I voted this up because it is quite useful, but I remark that it applies to a parametric surface, not curve. To do similarly with a curve one would perhaps take points thereon, and also convex combinations of (many) pairs of points. Then proceed as above. Example (saddle curve) to test with: `ParametricPlot3D[{(t^2 - 1)/(t^2 + 1), 
  2 t/(t^2 + 
      1), ((t^2 - 1)/(t^2 + 1))^2 - (2 t/(t^2 + 1))^2}, {t, -10, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, I added the extension, thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Following ruebenko's approach, after computing the convex hull you can much faster directly get the volume without triangulating the volume as 1/6 Sum[ Det [ triangle vertices ] ]:

```
Do[ -Total[
    Det[{ch[[1, #[[1]]]], ch[[1, #[[2]]]], ch[[1, #[[3]]]]}] & /@ 
       ch[[2]]]/6 , {10}]
(* 12.5077 *)
```

This is the 3d shoelace formula:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710682/algorithm-for-partially-filling-a-polygonal-mesh/14713130#14713130

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula

I must say I've searched pretty good for a link to  derivation/proof of this useful thing and come up empty.

Ok the derivation was not so hard to work out.. Note implict here is an assumption that the vertices of each triangle are ordered consistantly CW or CCW. Also this does not require convexity, only whatever connectivity restrictions follow from the divergance theorem.

[image]

Comment: +1 this is quite impressive, if you do find a deviation, I'd be very interested to hear about it.

Comment: @gerrge2079, thanks for the deviation. Very useful indeed.

Answer (score 7):

In **Version 10**, once the points have been obtained as per user21's approach, we can tetrahedralize them directly using `DelaunayMesh`

```
pf = {Cos[u], Sin[u] + Cos[v], Sin[v]};
pp = ParametricPlot3D[pf, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, -Pi, Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
data = Reap[ParametricPlot3D[Sow[pf], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, -Pi, Pi}]][[2, 1]];
pts = Cases[data, {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}];
```

Then:

```
del = DelaunayMesh[pts]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And the volume is computed easily using `RegionMeasure`

```
RegionMeasure[del]
```

> 12.5077258

Answer (score 7):

Here is another way that uses the `Graphics` object directly:

```
gr = ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u], Sin[u] + Cos[v], Sin[v]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, -Pi, Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We discretize the graphics using `DiscretizeGraphics`

```
mr = DiscretizeGraphics[Normal[gr /. (Lighting -> _) :> Lighting -> Automatic]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We compute the convex hull

```
hull = ConvexHullMesh[MeshCoordinates[mr]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And finally, we get the volume using `RegionMeasure`

```
RegionMeasure[hull]
```

> 12.5077258

OR `Volume`

```
Volume[hull]
```

> 12.5077258

As a bonus we can get the surface area of the `ParametricPlot` object:

```
RegionMeasure[mr, 2]
```

> 33.1870442

Same result can be obtained using `Area`

```
Area[mr]
```

> 33.1870442