# Probable Bug in ConvexHullMesh

Tags: bugs, computational-geometry

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and persisting through 10.2 or later**

---

Consider points taken from the following parametric plot. [See this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25811/how-to-calculate-the-volume-of-a-convex-hull)

```
pf = {Cos[u], Sin[u] + Cos[v], Sin[v]};
data = Reap[ParametricPlot3D[Sow[pf], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, -Pi, Pi}]][[2, 1]];
pts = Cases[data, {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}];

Graphics3D[{Red, Point[pts]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When I tried to compute the `ConvexHull` I was greeted with this error message and output:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Interesting!. Well, let's load the `TetGenLink` package:

```
Needs["TetGenLink`"]
```

We compute the `ConvexHull` again

```
tethull = TetGenConvexHull[pts]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which works fine as the output above and the following plot shows

```
Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[tethull[[1]], Polygon[tethull[[2]]]], Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Interestingly, one can easily compute the Delaunay tetrahedralization using `DelaunayMesh`:

```
DelaunayMesh[pts]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The question is, have I found a bug in `ConvexHullMesh`? I'm on **Windows 8.1**

Comment: Behavior confirmed in v10.0.0 under Windows 7.  Can any OSX or Linux users confirm?

Comment: Yes, it's a bug (also on Linux) which I am going to file and I am preparing an answer.

Comment: @user21. Thanks for the confirmation and I await your answer.

Comment: I can reproduce this on OS X as well.

Comment: Confirmed in Mac OS 10.9.4

Comment: still present in 10.0.2. checked on windows 7

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is at least one bug, possibly more. Let me explain:

If we go one step further and use

```
Needs["TetGenLink`"]
tethull = TetGenConvexHull[pts];
bmr = BoundaryMeshRegion[tethull[[1]], {Polygon[tethull[[2]]]}]

BoundaryMeshRegion::binsect: "The boundary curves self-intersect or cross each other in BoundaryMeshRegion[{{1.,-0.999551,-0.000449248},{0.900969,-0.566116,-4.48799*10^-7},{0.222521,-1.97493,-4.48799*10^-7},<<46>>,{0.222521,1.8759,-0.433884},<<5751>>},<<1>>]"
```

So we know why `ConvexHullMesh` failed, but I think `ConvecHullMesh` could be a little more informative about that. The next question is why are there self intersections or crossings? This is much harder to say, I suspect that some interplay with the duplicate coordinates and TetGen goes south. That is going to take some time to track down. It seems the points are too regular for TetGen.

A possible workaround (depending on the application of this) is to perturbe the input data a bit:

```
npts = pts + RandomReal[10^-6*{-1, 1}, {Length[pts], 3}];
ConvexHullMesh[npts]
```

[image]

I had another look at this one. To me it seems that there is an issue within TetGen for this specific input. Let's delete the duplicate coordinats:

```
pf = {Cos[u], Sin[u] + Cos[v], Sin[v]};
data = Reap[ParametricPlot3D[Sow[pf], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, -Pi, Pi}]][[2,
     1]];
pts = Cases[data, {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}];
Graphics3D[Point[pts]];
Length[pts]
(*pts=DeleteDuplicates[pts];*)

pts = Region`Mesh`DeleteDuplicateCoordinates[pts][[1]];
Length[pts]
```

Lets export the coordinates and run tetgen on the command line:

```
Needs["TetGenLink`"]
inst = TetGenCreate[];
TetGenSetPoints[inst, pts];
TetGenExport["test.node", inst]

./tetgen -E test.node
```

When we reimport the result we get intersecting facets:

```
coords = Developer`ToPackedArray@
   N@Import["test.1.node", 
       "Table"][[2 ;; -2]][[All, {2, 3, 4}]];
faces = Developer`ToPackedArray@
   Import["test.1.face", 
      "Table"][[2 ;; -2]][[All, {2, 3, 4}]];
Length[coords]
{pts2, intersectingFacets} = 
  TetGenDetectIntersectingFacets[coords, 
   Developer`ToPackedArray@Partition[faces, 1]];
Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[pts2, Polygon[intersectingFacets]]]
```

There is not much that can be done about this. I have informed the TetGen developer. Sorry about that.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I edited the answer (maybe you'll notice what changed) :)

Comment: @RunnyKine, thanks for that - it's an open secret I guess :-)

Comment: Can you comment on the inability of `VoronoiMesh` to handle 3D data? Is it coming anytime soon, perhaps in a point update?

Comment: @RunnyKine, it's being discussed but I can not say how hard or long it is do get implemented. It's always good to send such requests to the support. If there is a large enough interest, then it might get done quicker....

Comment: Well, the question of OP is 5 years ago, these days in mathematica 12.0, I encounter with this problem.

Comment: @HyperGroups, in version 12.0 `ConvexHullMesh[pts]` works just fine for me.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/212842/6648   maybe you can try this data.

Comment: @HyperGroups, works fine for me. You should report this then to WRI at support@wolfram.com. Someone there can help you track the issue down.

Comment: OK, I've reported, the data copied also works fine for me, so I deleted it. Maybe it like the operation of `npts = pts + RandomReal[10^-6*{-1, 1}, {Length[pts], 3}];`   I uploaded the sample data here, if you are interest. Any way, thank for your solution. https://github.com/HyperGroups/Mathematica/blob/master/Bug%26%26Problem/ConvexHullMesh%E7%9A%84%E4%B8%80%E4%BA%9B%E9%97%AE%E9%A2%98%40Problems%4012.0/%E6%97%A0%E6%B3%95%E8%AE%A1%E7%AE%97%E7%9A%84%E4%B8%80%E4%B8%AA%E9%97%AE%E9%A2%98%40CalculateFailed%40ConvexHullMesh/data%40ConvexHullMeshFailed.wdx

Answer (score 3):

In the current release, you can try the following:

```
pf = {Cos[u], Sin[u] + Cos[v], Sin[v]};

gr = ParametricPlot3D[pf, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, -Pi, Pi}];

mr = DiscretizeGraphics[gr // Normal]
```

[image]

Disregard the message about `Lighting` not supported, `DiscretizeGraphics[gr //Normal]` will remove the duplicated points

Now this will work:

```
ConvexHullMesh[MeshCoordinates[mr]]
```

[image]