# Finding the surface area of a 3D convex hull

Tags: computational-geometry, geometry

I have noted several instances [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/51377/7167) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55412/7167) where `ConvexHullMesh`, introduced in v10 has been used to greatly simplify some geometry problems.  Determining the volume of a region encompassing a set of 3D points, `pts` is now simply:

```
Volume@ConvexHullMesh@pts
```

Is there an equally simplified method for determining the surface area of this convex hull?

Note, the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConvexHullMesh.html) for `ConvexHullMesh` suggests that the area can be obtained, using `RegionMeasure`, however I suspect this is a typo, since `RegionMeasure` gives an area *only if the points have a dimension of 2*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Area@RegionBoundary@ConvexHullMesh@pts
```

For example, consider a cube, which has volume 1 and surface area 6:

```
pts = Tuples[{0, 1}, 3];
convexHull = ConvexHullMesh[pts];
convexHullSurface = RegionBoundary[convexHull];
RegionMeasure[convexHull, #] & /@ {0, 1, 2, 3}
(* {∞, ∞, ∞, 1.} *)
RegionMeasure[convexHullSurface, #] & /@ {0, 1, 2, 3}
(* {∞, ∞, 6., 0} *)
```

Comment: Nice - I was heading down that road, but took a wrong turn at some point.

Answer (score 11):

Here is another way to compute the surface area of a 3D convex hull:

```
SeedRandom[0]
pts = RandomReal[5, {50, 3}];
chull = ConvexHullMesh @ pts;
```

Then:

```
Tr @ PropertyValue[{chull, 2}, MeshCellMeasure]
```

> 86.8845076

**Update**

This approach is good because you have access to individual face areas and with `PropertyValue` you can do cool things like display the values of the areas on the mesh:

```
PropertyValue[{chull, {2, All}}, MeshCellLabel] = 
        Style[NumberForm[#, 3], Bold, Darker@Red, 15] & /@ 
                    PropertyValue[{chull, {2, All}}, MeshCellMeasure];
```

Then:

```
chull
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nice, I should have added benchmarking requirements to my original question just to make it challenging.

Answer (score 10):

For fun, here is an approach that uses the graphics generated from the mesh. Lets generate some points:

```
SeedRandom[0]
pts = RandomReal[5, {50, 3}];
chull = ConvexHullMesh @ pts;
```

Create a graphics object from it and discretize it:

```
gr = Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[MeshCoordinates[chull], {MeshCells[chull, 2]}]];
```

And here is the area:

```
Area @ DiscretizeGraphics @ gr
```

> 86.8845076

For comparison:

```
Area @ RegionBoundary @ chull
```

> 86.8845076

Comment: Always enjoy a "just for fun" approach.

Comment: @bobthechemist. yeah, me too.

Answer (score 1):

As of version 12, April 16,2019:

**Using `SurfaceArea`:**

```
SeedRandom[0]; (* example borrowed from @RunnyKine *)
pts = RandomReal[5, {50, 3}];

Through[{SurfaceArea, Volume}[ConvexHullMesh@pts]]
```

> {86.8845, 64.3916}

---

The other example:

```
pts = Tuples[{0, 1}, 3];
Through[{SurfaceArea, Volume}[ConvexHullMesh@pts]]
```

> {6., 1.}

Comment: Nice to see that `SurfaceArea` finally works in this context. Thanks for digging up an old post.